# AngularJS - $resource + ng-repeat issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngresource

In my html file I have the following table:

```
<div ng-controller="InstructorCtrl">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="instructor in instructors">
          <td>{{instructor.title}}</td>
          <td>{{instructor.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here's how controller looks:

```
angular.module('angularFrontendApp')
  .controller('InstructorCtrl', function ($scope, Instructor) {
    $scope.instructors = [];
    $scope.instructors = Instructor.query();
  });
```

Injected `Instructor` is the factory:

```
angular.module('angularFrontendApp')
  .factory('Instructor', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:9000/api/instructor');      
  });
```

Most of the time the table is rendered just fine:

[image: Correct rendering]

But I noticed that when I reload the page a few times, the table sometimes looks like so:

[image: Incorrect rendering]

I thought that the problem occurs when the `ng-repeat` kicks off when the `$resource`'s `$promise` is still not resolved. So I've set the breakpoint in my backend method which returns the list of `instructors`. When the execution was stopped, only the table header was rendered on the page. When the execution was continued and data sent from server, the table rendered just fine. Seems pretty strange to me.

Comment: can you post the result of Instructor.query().

Comment: check the response of the http-call using chrome developer tools or firebug or whatever when a reload has caused the empty table. This could very well be a problem with your backend. Also $scope.instructors = []; is not needed, the query(..) method will return an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.

I have taken the closer look at which methods have been called in the backend. It is actually a rare server-side issue that messed up routing.