# Not fetching data with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build an app with Angular JS that fetches data from a Django REST API.

I have this script

```
var userListApp = angular.module('userListApp', ['ngResource']);

userListApp.factory('Classroom', function($resource) {
      return $resource('/classrooms/:id/',
      {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray:false}}
      );
    });

userListApp.controller('UsersController', function($scope, Classroom) {
  Classroom.query(function(data) {
    $scope.classrooms = data;
  });
});
```

and this is the html

```
<div ng-app="userListApp">
    <div ng-controller="UsersController">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Classroom</th>
                    <th>School</th>
                    <th>Academic year</th>
                </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="classroom in classrooms">
                  <td>{{classroom.classroom}}</td>
                  <td>{{classroom.school}}</td>
                  <td>{{classroom.academic_year}}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I'm getting this error in the console

> Error: $resource:badcfg
>   Response does not match configured parameter
>   Error in resource configuration for action `query`. Expected response to contain an array but got an object (Request: GET /classrooms)

([from the error reference page of Angular JS](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg?p0=query&p1=array&p2=object&p3=GET&p4=%2Fclassrooms))

I was looking at some answers here on stackoverflow, and came to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20340521/3310628), and I tried to do what they say

```
userListApp.factory('Classroom', function($resource) {
      return $resource('/classrooms/:id/', 
      {method: 'classrooms', id: '*'},
      {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray:false}}
      );
    });
```

And I'm getting no error, but no data either. There are, however, some tables on the webpage, like if it's trying to "catch" something, here's a screenshot

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I've tried to put this line

```
return $resource('/classrooms/?format=json',
```

Instead of this

```
return $resource('/classrooms/:id/',
```

on the Angular app, and there's no data, but, if I go to developer tools on Network -> XHR, I get the json data

```
[{"school":{"id":1,"school_name":"IPSIA F. Lampertico","address":"Viale Giangiorgio Trissino, 30","city":"Vicenza"},"academic_year":"2015/2016","classroom":"1^A","floor":0,"students":[{"classroom":1,"first_name":"Stefano","last_name":"Rossi","gender":"M","birthday":"1998-06-22"},{"classroom":1,"first_name":"Luca","last_name":"Possanzini","gender":"M","birthday":"1999-11-22"}]
```

but, as I said, that data is not shown on the tables in the html.

**UPDATE 2:**

After adding "?format=json'" to the resource url, I get the exact amount of rows (in my data I have three classrooms, so I get three rows in the HTML table), but no data in it.

**UPDATE 3:**

I've added this line to debug the code

```
userListApp.controller('UsersController', function($scope, Classroom) {
  Classroom.query(function(data) {
    $scope.classrooms = data;
    console.log(data); <--- NEW LINE FOR THE DEBUG
  });
});
```

and now I get this, on the console log

[image]

Comment: Well, the screenshot shows that you do have data, since your table has many rows. They're empty, which means that the onjects you got don't have (or have empty) fields named classroom, school and academic_year. Open your browser dev tools, and look atwhat you really get.

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` is not in the correct format. The data you posted has missing `}]` in the end. Recheck your server response.

I replicated the whole scenario on my machine and your code worked perfectly fine.

**HTML:** Same as yours.

**Script:**

```
var userListApp = angular.module('userListApp', ['ngResource']);

userListApp.factory('Classroom', function($resource) {
      return $resource('http://localhost:9000/classrooms/1', //changed this line only.
      {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray:false}}
      );
    });

userListApp.controller('UsersController', function($scope, Classroom) {
  Classroom.query(function(data) {
    $scope.classrooms = data;
  });
});
```

`http://localhost:9000/classrooms/1` returns just the data that you specified with `}]` appended at the end.

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've copy-pasted it and I forgot to put the final "}]", because I actually have three "classrooms", but I've copied just the first. Anyway, the Json code is correct (I've validated it on https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), but I can't visualize the data anyway. Strange thing is that I see the exact amount of rows (three), but there's no data in it.

Comment: Are you sure `$scope.classrooms` contains the data? Did you debug at that point? Check your css. Maybe your text is the same colour as your background? And check whether the source has the text.

Comment: Yes, the same - without, obviously, the data.

Comment: Because of some reason Angular is not updating the binding. Try calling `$scope.$apply()` after`$scope.classrooms = data`

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112078/angularjs-resource-ng-repeat-issue) . Apart from that I've run out of ideas. I would say switch to `$http`